# Realm Object Server on Ubuntu : Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code)

Tags: ubuntu, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've just installed Realm Object Server on Ubuntu
and can't access dashboard on default port 9080.
Port is enabled in ufw.
Any ideas?

```
systemctl status
realm-object-server.service - Realm Sync Services
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/realm-object-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-09-27 21:26:10 UTC; 4min 19s ago
Main PID: 2614 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: What if you try to access the application from the same server is running? Try `curl http://localhost:9080` and see what happens.

Comment: There is a log file in `/var/log/realm-sync.log`, which might contain useful information. Can you paste it?

Comment: @Orlando 
`curl http://localhost:9080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9080: Connection refused`

and : 
`sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                                
9080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
...
`

Comment: @KristianSpangsege the log is empty

Comment: The server exited with status code 1, this usually means that it caught an exception and terminated. Attempting to connect to it, on any port, will always result in failure (that's why it is reported as `dead`).

This being said, `systemd` should have restarted the server automatically upon failure. The fact that the log is empty is very surprising, as well. Could you try running `realm-object-server --configuration /etc/realm/configuration.yml` and see if it outputs anything?

Thanks

Comment: @teotwaki please, check the [gist](https://gist.github.com/minikin/05057897a9471ee2ab9096ae3da3de26)

Comment: @Minikin Currently looking into this. Will get back to you ASAP. In the mean time, could you tell me if this is a new machine/AMI, or installed on your local machine? Do you have a specific version of NodeJS installed using NVM?

Comment: @Minikin I'm guessing that you have NodeJS 6.x installed on your machine. When we packaged the Realm Object Server, we built it against NodeJS 4.x, considering that's what shipped with Ubuntu by default.
I'll make sure that we add more `.deb` options to require a version `= 4.x`, so others don't hit the same issue as you. Do you have any way of setting up NodeJS 4.x on that machine?

Comment: @teotwaki Thanks!
new machine Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64) on Digital Ocean,
node -v v6.6.0 / npm -v 3.10.3

Comment: @teotwaki I'm going try tonight to run with node 4. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Minikin OK, cool. Just so you're aware, we'll try to update our packages to include support for NodeJS 4.x, 5.x and 6.x in the same DEB/RPM. I've put this pretty high on our priority list, but I can't tell you when we land this. I'll get back to you when I have more news.

Comment: @teotwaki Please, check the new [gist](https://gist.github.com/minikin/36a84867af696dc610ab507b10a67993)

Comment: @Minikin Could you give me the output of `node -v && which node`? It looks like you installed Node v4 using NVM, but the default install of Node is still v6. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Minikin The easiest route for you to get going, though, if this machine isn't useful to you (you said it was a brand new one), is to just redeploy it and only install the repo and the server. It will automatically pull in the correct Node dependency.

Comment: @teotwaki Thanks for the advice.I'll think abut it.
`:~$ node -v && which node v4.4.2 /usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: @Minikin So this confirms what I thought. I would suggest either removing the package-installed Node 6 from your machine if at all possible, or modify your `PATH` environment variable to ensure that `/usr/bin/env` can find the correct version of Node.

Comment: Any solution for this. I am slso having the exact same problem I set up nvm and tried form node 3.x to 4.x and still same result.

Comment: @teotwaki I completely removed and reinstalled node (4.x) and  have the same error.

Comment: @Minikin So `which -a node` only reports a single line?

Comment: @teotwaki recently I have two lines...
I think it would be great if you could provide additional 'pre-requirements' chapter here https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/

Comment: @Minikin We're working on ensuring that the packages handle this nicely. I'll keep you posted. Did you get it working over the weekend? I'd recommend going with a brand new CentOS7 machine and just following our docs; it should work out of the box. Do you use the machine for anything else, which requires you to have Node 6 or something? (Trying to understand the use case here).

Answer (score 0):

Tried with a new droplet on DO (Ubuntu 16.041):

1. **Do not install node manually!**
2. Follow the [instruction](https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/install-realm-object-server/)
3. Enjoy!